# Zend Framework: Select like query

Tags: php, zend-framework

That is my select function:

```
 public function search($for) {
    $q = $this->select()->from($this->_name, array('id', 'title', 'content'))
            ->where('title LIKE ?', "%$for%")
            ->orWhere('content LIKE ?', "%$for%")
            ->orWhere('keywords LIKE ?', "%$for%")
            ->where('is_visible = ?', 0)
            ->where('category = ?', 7);

    return $this->fetchAll($q);
}
```

But why if is_visible = 1 or category is different from 7 select and other rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that the AND/OR precedence is not being interpreted correctly. Try this:

```
$q = $this->select()->from($this->_name, array('id', 'title', 'content'))
        ->where("title LIKE '%$for%' OR content LIKE '%$for%' OR keywords LIKE '%$for%'")
        ->where('is_visible = ?', 0)
        ->where('category = ?', 7);
```